# M2 - Different tax class for different product in same region

Tags: magento2.2, tax

Here in Slovakia, we have some products types that are taxed differently from other products. For example electornic 20%, medical accessories 10%.

So I have created tax zones for 10% and 20%
[image]

And tax rules:
[image]

On the product I have configured that product X has 20% and product Y has 10%. (also reindexed, cleared / flushed cache, removed all directories like view_preprocessed,...)

Result is that, both products are calculated with 20%.

Tax calculation is set based on shipping origin, which is configured.

Here is similar question which has been not answered [Magento 2 - Two different tax percentage for two different products in same region](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207265/magento-2-two-different-tax-percentage-for-two-different-products-in-same-regi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the tax class from code in the import script it started working. So i am guessing that problem was, that magento saved from admin the value into wrong store view. Or other... since in DB I have value in DB for store view 0 and store view 1